# How to model this with Entity Framework Code First 6?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I've a problem trying to model this:

I've Managers and Customers. Then Sections and Departments.
A Manager can be Manager of a Section or a Manager of a Department or Manager of Both.
Also, a Manager can be a Customer at the same time.

Now, I don't want to have all of the Users table information duplicated in the database, so I created a parent class User.

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : User
{
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DepartmentCustomerAssignment> DepartmentCustomerAssignments { get; set; }

}

public class Manager : User
{
        public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class SectionManagerAssignment : Entity
{
    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }

    public int ManagerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    public int SectionId { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentManagerAssignment : Entity
{
    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }

    public int ManagerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentCustomerAssignment : Entity
{
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Now... let's take as example manager manager1@app.com.
His data is in the table Users and then there's a record in the Managers table (same Id since Manager it's inheriting from User, TPT)

The problem comes when I want to assign a departmentId to a User that's also a Manager, (we must make him Customer as well).

0) I get email of the customer in the webapi service and the departmentId
1) I look for the existing user with that email.
2) If doesn't exists...cool, no problem...I just create a new customer.
3) If it exists...it might be in Users table (since it's a Manager)
3.1) I look into the repository of Customer for a Customer with that email.
3.2) If it doesn't exists, I must create a new customer, but I need to use the same record id that's in User, because if not, I would be duplicating the email (and other data) of the manager, saved in the User table.

Is this model right? Is there any way to create the Customer without creating a new record in Users?

Comment: I think you might want to consider a design pattern here as I suspect inheritance may not work for this situation - something like the strategy pattern might be more like what you are after: http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern

Comment: I know the strategy pattern, but before going into behavior patterns I'd like to know that my model (and database) are OK, if not, I'll need to rewrite later a lot of code. You didn't tell me how you'd model this.